# I've studied vs I've been studying

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, perfect-aspect

What's the difference from these two phrases? How would I know if keep studying or if I did it in the past?

Comment: I've studied Spanish and Latin.  However, that was over 50 years ago.  Lately I've been studying Medicare plans.

Comment: When I say, "I have done it", it may mean a) a status update that one can verify, b) I have done it many times; so I am well-versed in doing it, c) Hurrah...I have done it.  Though it sounds like a past tense, it is a reflection of the present too; hence it is Present Perfect.  When I say, I have been doing it, I started it sometime in the past, have done it till now, and am likely to continue it.  I have been writing for many publications; I have been teaching.  Since the day I left home, I have been thinking of going back...